# Sikuli IDE can't import cucumber gem in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm using SikuliX IDE 1.1.2 (with JRuby support enabled), and I'm trying to get cucumber working from within the Sikuli IDE.

I have found this article which just covers what I need:
http://www.jmest.org/wp-content/uploads/JMESTN42350420.pdf

I have also found the related github and I am now trying to run a sample script in Ruby that I found here: https://github.com/rssdev10/sikulix-ide-templates/blob/master/examples/libreoffice-writer-test/test-cucumber.sikuli

But when I try to run this script from the Sikuli IDE, I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- cucumber/rspec/disable_option_parser require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939 require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54 start_cucumber at C:/Users/at080olimath/Downloads/sikulix-ide-templates-master/examples/libreoffice-writer-test/test-cucumber.sikuli:31 cucumber_test at C:/Users/at080olimath/Downloads/sikulix-ide-templates-master/examples/libreoffice-writer-test/test-cucumber.sikuli:56 SikulixCucumber at C:/Users/at080olimath/Downloads/sikulix-ide-templates-master/examples/libreoffice-writer-test/test-cucumber.sikuli:62 <top> at C:/Users/at080olimath/Downloads/sikulix-ide-templates-master/examples/libreoffice-writer-test/test-cucumber.sikuli:67 

[error] script [ test-cucumber ] stopped with error in line 31
[error] LoadError ( (LoadError) no such file to load -- cucumber/rspec/disable_option_parser )
```

On a Google Drive link, I was able to find a .jar file which contains all the gems needed (cucumber etc.), but the archive is old (2014) and contains a beta verison of the Sikuli IDE:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwx0cbtdU5K6STg2T0l5UWlIRXc

As per my understanding, I would need a way to build the sikulix.jar with the Cucumber gem included... But I cannot manage to figure out where to get started.

On this documentation page, I can also find that this is possible to include cucumber in sikuli.jar:
https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1

> If you want to experiment with the special JRuby support (rSpec,
>   cucumber, ...) you have to look into the modules JRubyAddOns and
>   JRubyGem. Both have to be built manually if needed (not contained in
>   the local developement build).

While I was able to find the JRubyGem, I am unable to find the JRubyAddOns anywhere... And I don't know what to do next :(

How should I proceed to get cucumber working from within the SikuliX IDE 1.1.2?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think stock Cucumber Gem has C-dependencies that won't execute VM-side for Jruby. This here: https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber-jvm/versions/2.0.1-java might be more what you're looking for. Good luck!